# AJAX Cursor - Sharepoint Visual Webpart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, sharepoint, web-parts

Am creating a custom SharePoint 2010 webpart.

I am new to AJAX so please help me on this.

Can anyone give me a step by step procedure to do the following:

On button Click:

1. disable the button
2. display a wait screen/wait animation / hourglass cursor
3. do a long job.
4. display in a text box that Job successfully completed.

To make it more easier to understand I am posting my code below:

Following is my VisualWebPart.ascx file:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisualWebPart1.ascx.cs" Inherits="AE_Project_Form.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1" %>

<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
        width: 26%;
        height: 248px;
    }

.wait{
        cursor:wait;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function ShowCursor() {    
document.getElementById('btn_Submit').disabled = true;
$(this).addClass("wait");    
     }
</script>

<table class="auto-style1">
<tr>
<td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">
<asp:Button ID="btn_Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Submit_Click" Text="Submit" Width="97px" Height="20px" />
</td>
</tr>
```

And now my VisualWebPart.ascx.cs file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing;
using System.Data;


namespace AE_Project_Form.VisualWebPart1
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
{
public VisualWebPart1()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();

        }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.btn_Submit.Attributes.Add("onClick", "ShowMessage()");
}
protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//Do a long process including some Database updates etc...


//Just show a MSGBOX saying process completed 

Type cstype = this.GetType();
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "PopupScript"))
{
 String cstext = "alert('Successfully Added  Project');";
cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "PopupScript", cstext, true);
 }

}
}
```

Now what I want the webpart to do is that when a button is clicked:

1. disable button and start the waiting cursor
2. Do the long database process
3. After the long process is complete show a message box that process completed .

But what happens is that the button is not disabled nor I see the waiting cursor. The long processor takes a long time as expected and just displays a final message box.

Am I wrong in my understanding of Javascript C# webpart coding here somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in my discussion here :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/09f6e65c-5d8c-4516-81f1-f48c21d20ef0/?prof=required

Please see the last reply from Jack ... It worked for me thanks ...